# Stay connected {to/with/ on} our Facebook page (prepositional confusion)

Tags: prepositions, prepositional-phrases

Which preposition is appropriate? *On*, *with* or *to*?

1. Stay updated **with**/**on** our Facebook page
2. Stay connected **to**/**on**/**with** our Facebook page
3. Stay updated on the go **on**/**with** our Facebook page
4. Stay connected on the go **to**/**on**/**with** our Facebook page.

Comment: I would not use any of these. All of them are equally bad to me. Also, Facebook still exists?

Comment: Don't use Facebook. It is evil.

Comment: Face book? Who is this face book?

Answer (score -1):

I like *with*, and would also break this into two sentences, like so:

> On the go? Stay connected with Facebook!

**via** might also make sense:

> Stay connected on the go **via** Facebook.

Since this is slang-ish marketing-speak, in the spirit of *Googling* a topic, or when you *inbox* someone, you could always *verb* the word; as in

> Facebook us to stay connected!

(...dodges coffee cup thrown my way...)